# How would I build this with such a background while keeping it responsive in HTML/CSS/Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build this design in HTML/CSS (see image below), but I am having trouble getting the background in with the number.

So far I have tried using a background image SVG - but on resize it is either getting stretched or the content does not fit anymore.

What I have so far:

```css
.steps .step {
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}

.steps .step .topblock {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.steps .step .topblock .numberholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.steps .step .topblock .numberholder .number {
  color: #FE6631;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 47px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.steps .step .topblock h3 {
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.steps .step .topblock ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.steps .step .topblock ul li {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.steps .step .bottomblock {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container steps">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="topblock" style="background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)"
      ;="">
      <div class="numberholder">
        <p class="number">1</p>
      </div>

      <h3>A tailor-made offer</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>For the (starting) entrepreneur</li>
        <li>At least four months of Chamber of Commerce registration</li>
        <li>A full lease financing</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomblock">
      <h3>Full lease financing for entrepreneurs</h3>
      <p>Full lease financing for entrepreneurs At there is a unique opportunity for entrepreneurs to fully lease or finance the desired car. The car is then simply owned. But instead of counting down a large amount at once, you pay the...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="topblock" style="background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)"
      ;="">
      <div class="numberholder">
        <p class="number">2</p>
      </div>

      <h3>At a competitive financial lease rate</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Annual figures without transfer</li>
        <li>Lease or financing with renowned lease and financing partners</li>
        <li>At attractive conditions</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomblock">
      <h3>Leasing or financing has never been easier</h3>
      <p>In order to be able to offer the best conditions, we quickly and professionally compare all quotations from our lease and financing partners. We then offer you the best offer, fully customized. Without you having to worry about this or put in the
        time. No financial statements, ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="topblock" style="background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)"
      ;="">
      <div class="numberholder">
        <p class="number">3</p>
      </div>

      <h3>Arranged within 24 hours</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Good advice about monthly payments</li>
        <li>All-in lease price: you know exactly where you stand in advance</li>
        <li>The car is directly your property</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomblock">
      <h3>We advise you on which car fits which monthly costs</h3>
      <p>In addition,  protects you from too high charges. We use an automated credit check based on financial data from the Chamber of Commerce. If these figures show that the monthly costs for the car you have selected are too high, we will draw
        your attention to this....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This only gives me the correct result on a certain viewport width and does not work well responsive.

Thanks in advance

screenshot of design that I need to convert to HTML/CSS

[image]

What I have so far (which looks almost correct on this viewport width)

[image]

What happens on smaller screens

[image]

What happens on bigger screens
[image]

Comment: I added the full rendered code. Thought it would look a little less messy if I pasted in just the Twig and SCSS

Comment: This is quite a hassle, but you will most likely need to cut that background in many parts. The 2 sides on one hand. The top on the other, and the bottom as well. 
You will then have to do a balancing act on what you scale and what you don't (nothing should stretch horizontally, for example), and what you crop (top and bottom images). Is it worth the trouble though? If these were rectangles, you would only have to have the top image and the rest would be doable with CSS...

Comment: That sounds too much for what we can do. I will make changes in the design so it's easier to do in HTML/CSS. Thank you @VictoriaRuiz

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your screenshots and tried for myself. So basically what your problem is your background image doesn't stick in the middle so to correct add this **code**:

```
 background-position: center;
```

to this class

```
.steps .step .topblock {
```

this will fix this problem for all screens other than mobile i think.

How it is suppose to look :

```
.steps .step .topblock {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

and about your mobile responsiveness problem you need to work with media queries.

and since your background has a static height because you used (`background-size: contain;`)

you need to change that to make it look better on phone and that would be this code that covers the background instead of trying to contain itself into a small area:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .steps .step .topblock {
background-size: cover;
}
```

Glad to be help. Let me know if you have questions!